# Facebook API get user local time without FBML

Tags: facebook, localization, fbml, xfbml, facebooktoolkit

I'm writing a Facebook Iframe canvas application using the [Facebook Toolkit](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/).
There is a certain action where I need to store the date and time for the action, and in the future I want to render it for the user as a date and time like (10:05 AM 20 September 2010).

The problem here is that each facebook user has his own local date and time. I found a solution using the FBML tag  but I'm looking for a non-fbml approach.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using FQL:

```
select timezone from user where uid = <user_id>
```

see [`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user) table